# Budgie Preview applet not working

Tags: application-switcher, budgie

I have recently installed Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 and my <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> behavior is still the old style (no preview). I've tried re-installing the applet (I never see any icon for it in the top bar either).

I tried binding a keyboard shortcut to `/usr/lib/budgie-desktop/plugins/budgie-wprviews/wprviews_window` as per the [budgie-extras GitHub](https://github.com/UbuntuBudgie/budgie-extras/tree/master/budgie-wpreviews).

How do I get the preview of the application in the application switcher?

Comment: Have you  added the window previews applet to your panel via budgie-settings?